# How to enable support for sass in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass

I use codekit to compile sass, on the configuration I added "full debug info". I also enambled "support for sass" in the experiments settings on chrome and also enabled source maps.
Still it does not work

I watched a video where Paul Irish talks about this and on this "experiments" tab he enables "sass stylesheet debugging", I dont have that in my tab.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that sass debugging is no longer in the Experiments section and is now part of Chrome Developer Tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to activate the experiments. To do so, open `chrome://flags/` and activate `Developer Tools Experiments`.

After restarting Chrome you should have the Experiments tab as well.

Comment: thanks for your help. do you know to activate the workspace as well. I did some google search and on may 3013 the feature was only in canary, is it on the normal chrome now - thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else ends up here after struggling to make Chrome work with Sass, you need to run a different command to generate source maps via command line: `sass --watch --sourcemap sass/styles.scss:styles.css` instead of `--debug-info`.﻿
More info: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/tips-and-tricks#debugging-sass